# How can I use lean times?

Tags: sentence-construction

> You would have lean times unless you study more.

Is it awkward?
I wanna say that you should study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lean times** is OK, but your verb tenses are not right.

If you want to advise or warn someone that they will experience hardship in the future if they do not dedicate themselves to their studies now:

> You **will have** lean times ahead unless you **study** more now.

If you want to tell someone what the results would be **if** a person failed to study, as a hypothetical case:

> If you **didn't study**, you **would have** lean times ahead.

Answer (score -3):

This is not an expression as far as I know...

You can just say "You will have hard times unless you study more"

Comment: Best google **lean times**!